# Adding points to 3d plot in r

Tags: r, graphics, 3d

I'm beginner with plotting in 3D in R and I need help. I try to plot some easy paraboloid

```
library(rgl)
x <- seq(-1,1, 0.2)
y <- x
f <- function(x,y){
   -(x^2+y^2)
}
z <- outer(x,y, "f")
persp3d(x, y, z, col="gray")
```

So, my questions are:

1. Can I draw only grid, or make color transparent to see also the part of "at the back"?
2. How to add points to the plot (on the surface, e.g to draw in other color point (1,1,2))?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See `?material3d` for information on surface properties.  Most of these properties, such as `alpha` or `front="line"` or `back="line"`, can be passed directly to `persp3d()`.  Add points with `points3d()` (or `spheres3d()`).

```
persp3d(x, y, z, col="gray", alpha=0.5)
points3d(1,1,2,col="red")
persp3d(x, y, z, col="gray", front="line", back="line")
spheres3d(1,1,2,col="red",radius=5)  ## appropriate radius: I used x <- y <- 1:20
```